# countably compact and compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups

I know that compact space is countably compact, and every compact is pseudo-compact.

> **Is there a simple example that show any Compact space is not necessarily compact
>    ?**
>
> **Is there an example to show that any pseudo-compact space is not necessarily compact?**

Comment: What does it mean for a space to be compressed?

Comment: Excuse me, compact.I edited it.

Comment: two more comments:  in your first sentence, did you mean to write "*and every compact space is pseudo-compact*", and in your first question, the word compressed still appears.  Should it instead be "*Is there a simple example to show that a countably compact space is not compact*"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, your initial statement is incorrect.  The correct implications are as follows:
$$\text{compact}\;\;\implies\;\;\text{countably compact}\;\;\implies\;\;\text{pseudocompact}$$
(Note that "countably compact" is *not* the same as "$\sigma$-compact.")
To see that the reverse implications do not hold in general, consider the first uncountable ordinal endowed with the order topology which is countably compact space but not compact.

An example of a pseudocompact space which is not countably compact is harder to construct, but a good one can be found [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/).